# He may have called me yesterday at 5 p.m

Tags: grammar

İs it correct to say "He may have called me yesterday at 5 p.m." to imply i am not sure but it is possible that he called me yesterday at 5 p.m. ?

İ think using present perfect tense with a specific time marking isn't correct and there is a perfect infinitive with *may.*

Comment: All it means is that it's possible. Even if you knew for a fact, one way or the other, you could still say that.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly correct. The "may have + verb (past tense)" implies a possibility of an event in the past which probably cannot be acknowledged to have really happened since none can say for sure if it really did happen or not.

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely correct to say that

> **He may or might have called me yesterday at 5 P.M**.

It is not present perfect but refers to **a past action** which might or might not have   happened.It is also an illusion to believe that **might** is the past form of **may** except in the reported speech and in hypothetical 
conditions. So  the difference between may and might is very slight.

Here is the link.

http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/comparing-may-and-might